# Unable to properly get common elements between 4 arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get common elements which are exactly in each of 4 arrays using this code.

But it looks like it is counting in any elements that are common on even two or three of arrays. But I need to get the common element that are repeated in all four arrays. How can I fix this?

```js
let newArr = [];

function common(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4) {

  newArr = arr1.filter(function(v) {
    return arr2.indexOf(v) >= 0;
  })
  newArr.concat(arr2.filter(function(v) {
    return newArr.indexOf(v) >= 0;
  }));
  newArr.concat(arr3.filter(function(v) {
    return newArr.indexOf(v) >= 0;
  }));
  newArr.concat(arr4.filter(function(v) {
    return newArr.indexOf(v) >= 0;
  }));
}

common([1, 2, 6, 5, 9], [1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 9], [6, 5, 4, 5], [8, 2, 1, 6, 4]);

$('div').text(newArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Newer versions of javascript offer `Array.prototype.includes`, so if you have an array and want to know if it has a value, `theArray.includes(value)` will return true or false.  If you filter over the first array, and return only the elements that are included in the other arrays, fairly straight forward.  Even without the `includes()` method, using indexOf can do the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some `filter` calls with `indexOf` like so:

```js
let newArr = [];

function common(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4) {
  newArr = arr1.filter(function(e) {
    return arr2.indexOf(e) > -1 && arr3.indexOf(e) > -1 && arr4.indexOf(e) > -1;
  });
}

common([1, 2, 6, 5, 9], [1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 9], [6, 5, 4, 5], [8, 2, 1, 6, 4]);

$('div').text(newArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `reduce()` like a sieve to continuously filter the filtered result as you go with `includes()`

```js
let s = [[1, 2, 6, 5,9], [1, 2, 3, 6, 5,9], [ 6, 5, 4, 5], [8, 2, 1, 6, 4]];

let common = s.reduce((common, arr) => common.filter(item => arr.includes(item)))
console.log(common)
```

Answer (score 1):

This version of a solution lets you pass in an indeterminant number of arrays.  So long as it does not find an array that the number is not in, it will include the number in the results.

```js
function common() {
  var firstArray = arguments[0];
  var otherArrays = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  
  if (!otherArrays) return firstArray;
  
  return firstArray.filter(function(element){
    return otherArrays.filter(function(otherArray){
      return otherArray.indexOf(element) < 0;
    }).length == 0;
  });
}

var result = common([1, 2, 6, 5, 9], [1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 9], [6, 5, 4, 5], [8, 2, 1, 6, 4]);

$('div').text(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

If you know you have browser support for `Array.prototype.every`, this logic could be reduced some.

```js
function common() {
  var firstArray = arguments[0];
  var otherArrays = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  
  if (!otherArrays) return firstArray;
  
  return firstArray.filter(function(element){
    return otherArrays.every(function(otherArray){
      return otherArray.indexOf(element) > -1;
    });
  });
}

var result = common([1, 2, 6, 5, 9], [1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 9], [6, 5, 4, 5], [8, 2, 1, 6, 4]);

$('div').text(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: That's a nice idea. I would be tempted to filter on `otherArrays.every(arr => arr.includes(element))` rather than the inner filter which would allow it to exit early and avoid creating the temp array.

Comment: I need to check the browser support for `every()`.  I was trying to keep it relatively low.

Comment: IE 9, not bad.  Could be used.